# Загрузка библиотеки на PyPi

Tags: python, pypi

Есть некоторый модуль **JetORM**

вот иерархия проекта:

```
10.10.2021  00:16               108 .gitignore
07.10.2021  18:53    <DIR>          backups
10.10.2021  17:11    <DIR>          jetorm
10.10.2021  17:08               108 push_on_the_pypi.bat
10.10.2021  16:47                 0 pyproject.toml
10.10.2021  10:44               556 README.md
07.10.2021  18:16                26 requirements.txt
10.10.2021  16:32    <DIR>          tests
```

вот иерархия основного модуля JetORM, где лежит весь код:

```
10.10.2021  17:11    <DIR>          .
10.10.2021  17:11    <DIR>          ..
07.10.2021  18:54                74 .gitignore
10.10.2021  17:11    <DIR>          dist
10.10.2021  17:11    <DIR>          jetorm.egg-info
10.10.2021  10:20            16 359 jetorm.py
07.10.2021  18:09    <DIR>          Lib
07.10.2021  18:10               408 pyvenv.cfg
07.10.2021  18:17    <DIR>          Scripts
10.10.2021  17:10               676 setup.py
09.10.2021  21:52             3 270 _jetorm_methods.py
26.09.2021  19:17               542 __init__.py
```

я пользуюсь батником, в котором прописаны все команды, вот батник:

```
@echo off

echo Push is starting...

cd jetorm/

python setup.py sdist

twine upload dist/*

pause
```

всё проходит успешно, модуль загружен на PyPi. Я запускаю виртуальное окружение и устанавливаю jetorm и когда импортирую модуль строчкой:

```
import jetorm
```

Он, не находя модуль, выбивает ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jetorm'
```

Вот содержимое `setup.py`:

```
import io
import os
from setuptools import setup

# Use the README.md content for the long description:
with io.open("../README.md", encoding="utf-8") as fileObj:
    long_description = fileObj.read()

setup(
    name='jetorm',
    version='1.5',
    url='https://github.com/immadev2k21/JetORM',
    author='kapitanov',
    author_email='<leonidmilk2007@gmail.com>',
    description=('JetORM is the simplest ORM of its kind.'),
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    license='MIT',
    install_requires=['pymysql', 'prettytable'],
    keywords="db database orm ORM jet JetORM jetorm easy simple"
)
```

Версия 1.5, потому что было много попыток.
Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Вы забыли указать параметр `packages`, в итоге библиотека создалась полностью пустая. Прежде чем делать `twine upload`, проверяйте, что в папке `dist` лежит корректный результат

Answer (score 0):

Предпалагаю модуль был установлен... см базовую стурктуру модуля и файл `__init__.py` в корне модуля. В данном случае возможно следует использовать from jetcheto import jetcheto