# Не импортируется модуль

Tags: python, pypi

Есть модуль: https://pypi.org/project/jetorm/0.2/, я его пытаюсь импортировать (я его установил командой `pip install jetorm`, а также проверил наличие модуля в `pip list`):

```
import jetorm

print('Test import module')
```

Получаю ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jetorm'`, что, собственно говоря, не так?

Comment: Я вам вчера уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336931/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pypi#comment2366298_1336931), что вы в `setup.py` забыли указать параметр `packages`, в итоге библиотека создалась полностью пустая и никакого jetorm внутри неё не существует. Но вы почему-то решили меня проигнорировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет там никакого кода полезного совершенно. Пакет размером в 2кб - вы думаете там что-то должно быть реально?

Comment: это мой модуль, который я разрабатываю.

Comment: и весит он 19 кб. И вот по поводу полезного кода поспорю. Как вы можете утверждать об этом?) Интересно

Comment: ну там просто пусто. README и setup.py. Самого модуля там нет.

Comment: какие 19кб? я сейчас скачивал его с сайта - там 2кб

Comment: Files for jetorm, version 0.2
Filename, size File type Python version Upload date Hashes
jetorm-0.2.tar.gz (1.8 kB) Source None about 1 hour ago

Comment: странно... что я делаю не так...

Comment: @KLEYZYツ в третий раз сообщаю вам, что вы в `setup.py` забыли указать параметр `packages`

Comment: получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В документации написано установить еще зависимые модули

```
$ pip install pymysql
$ pip install prettytable
```

И попробуйте такой импорт

```py
from jetorm import sqlite
```

Comment: Сами-то проверяли работоспособность своего ответа?

Comment: он сам устанавливает нужные пакеты

Comment: @andreymal Конечно нет, что я буду ставить все подряд что ли? Я читаю документацию, там написано так. Если это не работает, то зачем вообще это использовать. Нет указаний по поддерживаемым версиям

Comment: @Dmitry советую вам не злоупотреблять написанием непроверенных ответов, это засоряет базу знаний и не даёт никакой пользы автору вопроса

Comment: @andreymal ставьте минус, удалю. Но написанные пакеты несколько дней назад, без соответствующей документации не будет являться мусором?

Comment: а вы сможете за 40 минут написать всю документацию?) Вы не подумали, что это бета-версия?))

Comment: зачем публиковать неготовый модуль вообще?

Comment: @KLEYZYツ здесь не дискуссионный клуб и не площадка для рекламы библиотек

Comment: лол, я залил модуль, потому что в первый раз это делаю) Какая может быть реклама? Ради чего? Мне деньги не приходят( я спросил вопрос, вы ответили, зачем напрашиваться на беседу не по теме?)))